# Extended Liouville Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Use the extended Liouville Theorem to prove that if $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial $p$ of degree $n>0$, then $p$ is divisible by $z-\alpha$.  Do not use the Euclidean Algorithm.

Well I know that by the Extended Liouville Theorem I can write $$|p(z)|\leq A+B|z|^{n}.$$

I divide by $|z-\alpha|$ to obtain $$\left|\frac{p(z)}{z-\alpha}\right|\leq\frac{A+B|z|^n}{|z-\alpha|}.$$

I want to simplify the right side so that it looks like $C+D|z|^{n-1}$ for some $C,D>0$, but I am not sure how to proceed.  I guess I need some inequality tricks or something.

Answer (score 0):

For $|z| > |\alpha| + 1$ we have $|p(z)/(z-\alpha)| \le |p(z)|$.

Comment: I like that.  But what if $|z|\leq|\alpha|+1$?

Comment: @nonremovable: This shows that $z \mapsto {p(z) \over z-\alpha}$ is (essentially) a polynomial.

Comment: I'm sorry, copper.hat but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @nonremovable: the constant term on the right is there to take care of $|z| \le |\alpha|+1$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Robert.  Would you care to go into some detail with your last response?  Sorry that I'm being so thickheaded.